# i used UIActionSheet in peoplePickerNavigationController, and tried to presentModalViewController: in UIActionSheetDelegate, which failed

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet

the situation is like:

theres a button in UIView A, which will lead us to the contact picker after pressing it:

```
        ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker=[[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc]init];
        picker.peoplePickerDelegate=self;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
```

and i used an UIActionSheet in the picker, to go to different Views according to the user's selection:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"ViewB",@"ViewC",@"ViewD",@"ViewE",nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:picker.view];
    [actionSheet release];
        return NO;
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex==0)
        [self gotoViewB];
    else if(buttonIndex==1)
        [self gotoViewC];
    else if(buttonIndex==2)
        [self gotoViewD];
    else if(buttonIndex==3)
        [self gotoViewE];
}

-(void)gotoViewB{
    ViewB *bClass=[[ViewB alloc]init];
    [self presentModalViewController:bClass animated:YES];
    [bClass release];
}
```

but after i selected a row in the contact picker view, nothing happened as the picker view didnt disappear and ViewB didnt show. i dont know whats wrong here so plz lend me a hand :<

Comment: try dismissing the peoplePicker. Your view B might be loading beneath it.

Comment: you mean define peoplePicker as a class instance and dismiss it in UIActionSheetDelegate? it makes sense and im trying!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add naviagation controller atfirst then call `"presentModelViewController"`

```
yourModelController =[[Yourmodelcontroller alloc]init];
UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: yourModelController];
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

Comment: presentModalViewController worked fine outside the UIActionSheetDelegate! when i first called dismissModalViewControllerAnimated and then presentModalViewController everything went OK! i just wanna know how to presentModalViewController inside UIActionSheetDelegate under this situation!